# Moving CLion project to Linux from Windows

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, include, clion

So I recently moved a clion project from windows to linux, it just doesnt work now. Cmake tells me I have a load of undefined references even though it worked on windows. Its also telling me every function defined in the headers is declared but never used. Im very confused as everything seems to be correct including the CMakeLists.txt file

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: It is a requirement of Stack Overflow for question post to have the code and error messages as a **text**, not *images*. Please, fix that problem with the question. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Turns out inline functions behave differently in C99 meaning the compiler was seeing an undefined reference, to fix it I added static infront of every inline that was only needed internally